# Timestamps in the VS Code Terminal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

For performance benchmarking, I'd like to see Node execution times at the line level in my terminal output (as opposed to the total execution time). It would be helpful to know if my code changes are increasing speed.

Using VS Code. Any recommended extensions?